# module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'unique_object_name'

Tags: python, keras

This is the error I can't figure out.

```
module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'unique_object_name'
```

This is what I'm importing:

```
import cv2
import os
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
from pygame import mixer
import time
```

I get the error when I try and run this line:

```
model = load_model('C:/Users/Henry/Downloads/Drowsiness detection/Drowsiness detection/models/cnnCat2.h5')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `keras.models.load_model()` probably worked properly before Keras become part of Tensorflow.

If you are using newer version of tf you should call this to load model:

```
tf.keras.models.load_model()
```